# (Psalm 141:5) the righteous should correct us in a kind manner Or saying correcting by and in itself is kindness

Tags: translation-philosophy, layers-of-meaning, metaphor

> Psalm 141:5 New American Standard Bible 1995
>
> 5  Let the righteous smite me [a]in kindness and reprove me; It is oil
> upon the head; Do not let my head refuse it, [b]For still my prayer is
> [c]against their wicked deeds.

> Psalm 141:5 New King James Version
>
> 5  Let the righteous strike me; It shall be a kindness. And let him
> rebuke me; It shall be as excellent oil; Let my head not refuse it.
>
> For still my prayer is against the deeds of the wicked.

> 141:5 תהילים
> The Westminster Leningrad Codex
>
> 5 יֶֽהֶלְמֵֽנִי־צַדִּ֨יק׀ חֶ֡סֶד וְֽיוֹכִיחֵ֗נִי שֶׁ֣מֶן רֹ֭אשׁ
> אַל־יָנִ֣י רֹאשִׁ֑י כִּי־ע֥וֹד וּ֝תְפִלָּתִ֗י בְּרָעוֹתֵיהֶֽם׃

The NASB1995 and the NKJV translation for letting the righteous people to correct us can be interpreted in different ways:

1. As per the NASB1995, it seems like it's saying that the righteous should correct us in kindness which means in a compassionate/gracious manner
2. As per the NKJV, it seems like it's saying that whenever the righteous corrects us(regardless of whether it's in a harsh manner or a compassionate/gracious manner), it is still kindness.  In other words, the act of correcting is kindness by and in itself.

Could someone please read & evaluate the Hebrew, and provide a more accurate assessment?

Answer (score 2):

Psalm 141:5 New American Standard Bible 1995

> 5a Let the righteous smite me **in kindness** and reprove me;

NASB translated from the LXX:

```
παιδεύσει με δίκαιος    ἐν ἐλέει                καὶ ἐλέγξει με
                        in mercy/kindness
```

On the other hand,
Psalm 141:5 New King James Version

> 5a Let the righteous strike me; It **shall be a kindness**.

let his rebuke
וְֽיוֹכִיחֵ֗נִי (wə·yō·w·ḵî·ḥê·nî)
Conjunctive waw | Verb - Hifil - Conjunctive imperfect - third person masculine singular | first person common singular
Strong's 3198: To be right, reciprocal, to argue, to decide, justify, convict

be an act of loving devotion.
**חֶ֡סֶד** (ḥe·seḏ)
**Noun** - masculine singular
Strong's 2617: Kindness, piety, reproof, beauty

OP: (Psalm 141:5) the righteous should correct us in a kind manner Or saying correcting by and in itself is kindness

That depends on the manuscript. LXX suggests the former; Hebrew manuscript suggests the latter.

At https://biblehub.com/psalms/141-5.htm, only 5 out of 28 uses "in kindness" (former). The rest follows the MT.

Comment: I suppose my follow-up question would deserve an entire new question posting by itself, or LOL an entire blog/website.  How would we Christian in general go about defending said discrepancy in different bible manuscripts in the field of Apologetics?

Comment: This is not a hermeneutic question but an apologetic one. You are welcome to ask it at https://www.facebook.com/groups/129702255041932 :)